# Maximum number of Partition in a Cassandra Table and How it depends on Disk space?

Tags: cassandra

I am using Cassandra DB, i want to know what could be the maximum number of partitions that can be made ?

Will more number of partition impact on the performance of Cassandra ?

how number of partition depend on the disk space ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no maximum number of partitions in Cassandra (that I know of). The number of partitions does have an impact on performance, and the more the better (this implies a good distribution of data which is exactly what you want for scalability). Disk space has nothing to do with it. You'll use whatever you're going to store.